# JOptionPane Input Dialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Can someone enlighten me on java? The code below is just using JOptionPane and more on inputdialog box for getting data on the user.

Concept:
First option is to select transaction then if they press S another input dialog shows asking for a PIN and then after the PIN another input dialog shows with 4 options for example withdrawing,checking balance, depositing and exit.

What is the process of showing another input dialog and then what is the process of going back to previous input dialog? And then what is the process of validating user input to show a message dialog first if the input is wrong and then go back to the previous input dialog?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myOptions = "S = Select Transaction\n"
            + "Q = Quit\n"
            + "Enter your choice";
        String myPin = "Enter your PIN";
        String Y = "Yes";
        String N = "No";
        String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            null, myOptions, "Computerized Automatic Teller Machine", 1);
        if (value.equals("S")) {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                null, myPin, "Computerized Automatic Teller Machine", 1);
        } else if (value.equals("Q")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, "Are you sure you want to exit?",
                "Computerized Automatic Teller Machine", 1);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, "Please the correct letter!",
                "Computerized Automatic Teller Machine", 1);
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, myOptions,
                "Computerized Automatic Teller Machine", 1);
        }
    }
}//end of class
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class main {
/**
 * @param args
 */

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String myOptions="S = Select Transaction\n"+
    "Q = Quit\n"+"Enter your choice";

    String myPin="Enter your PIN";
    String Y = "Yes";
    String N = "No";

    String value = null; // CHANGES START HERE
    boolean access = false;
    while (!access){
         value=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,myOptions,"Computerized Automatic Teller Machine",1);

          if (value.equals("S") ){
                String pin = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, myPin, "Computerized Automatic Teller Machine", 1);
                if (pin.equals("correctpin")){ // <<------ Here you do correct checks for pin
                    access = true;
                    continue;
                } // if pin
          }// if value

          else if(value.equals("Q") ){
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to exit?","Computerized Automatic Teller Machine", 1);
          }// elseif vale

          else{
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please the correct letter!","Computerized Automatic Teller Machine", 1);
              continue; //<--- !S and !Q send to the top of the loop
          }// else
      }// while access
    } // main
}//end of class
```

Ok so used a boolean to check if access is granted.
You will have to put in you own checks for the pin and the

```
continue;
```

will return to the top of the loop. Let me know if you need me to clarify further.

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  * * * * * * * * * * * * /

In answer to your comment below :

```
public boolean getPersonalInfo(int ...){  // <------------- return a boolean

    boolean result = false;
    while (!result){ // again to keep looping for a valid input
        // Your code here...
        // ... ... ... ... 
        if ("".equals(msg))  // to make sure your query has found something
                             // and all other validation checks
            // Action for failed query
        else{
            result = true;
            // Display msg (showMessageDialog) etc
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

then to call this

```
if (getPersonalInfo(int)){
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. I think I understand your codes. I will try it now and will let you know :)

Comment: Hi it works. My next trouble is the PIN should look from the database. How can I insert the method for finding it on the table of the database. Below is my other class for reading the information from the database.

Comment: public void getPersonInfo(int selID){
try{
 String msg="";
 String myQuery="";
 myQuery="SELECT LastName,FirstName FROM"+
   "tblPerson WHERE PersonID =" + selID;
 Statement myCommand=con.createStatement();
 ResultSet selRecord=myCommand.executeQuery(myQuery);
 selRecord.next();
 msg="ID"+ " "+ "Name\n";
 msg+=selID + " "+ selRecord.getString(1) + " " + selRecord.getString(2);
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
 selRecord.close();
 myCommand.close();
}catch(Exception e){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
  }
 } 
}

Comment: How can i insert it on if else statement inside your while loop? :)

Comment: I've expanded my answer . It acceptable? Let me know otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, to add logic to your multiple dialog boxes, you will need to put them inside a while loop.

```
boolean ok=false;
while (!ok){
  ... do your dialog boxes

  if (... check your stuff here...) ok=true;
}
```

**Secondly**, consider using a single dialog with all the questions in.
You can create one by using JDialog.

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
   JDialog d=new JDialog();
   d.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));
   d.add(new JLabel("Quesition 1"));
   JTextField f1=new JTextField();
   d.add(f1);
   ... same for a second question ...
   JButton ok=new JButton("OK");
   d.add(ok);
   ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
     if(f1.getText().equals(" ... do your testing here )){ 
       JDialog.this.setVisible(false);
     }
   }});
   d.show();

   String s1=f1.getText();
   ... get your validated values here ...
}
```

**Thirdly**:
 Is security an issue here? You should consider using code to prevent passwords from being grabbed - e.g. JPasswordField